# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.cal/com.test.cal.CalculatorActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android

Hi. I tried to create a calculator app for Android. Tried to code to show two buttons such that clicking on one of them displays it in a text box.

The code is:

```
package com.test.cal;

android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CalculatorActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    EditText ans;
    Button b1,b2;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ans = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ans);
        b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
        b2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(arg0.getId())
        {
        case R.id.one:
                ans.setText(1);
            break;
        case R.id.two:
                ans.setText(2);
            break;
        default:Toast.makeText(this, "fuckoff", 1000);
            break;  
        }
     }
   }
```

Clicking on the null point exception goes to the:

```
b2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
```

line. Please help. I am a beginner. Searched stack overflow, but didn't understand the few answers related to it.

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, your all views are **null** because you are trying to defined (accessing) the views before `setContentView(R.layout.main);`

Just change line of codes,

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ans = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ans);
        b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
        b2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
```

Put

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

before accessing the Views defined in your **main.xml** file..

Answer (score 2):

please Change oncreate. write like this

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ans = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ans);
        b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
        b2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put below code

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

**before accessing the Views defined (initialization of button and edittext) .**

**It’s important that you add below code after setContentView(R.layout.main); otherwise you will get an exception and your application will crash. Reason for this is, that you can’t use findViewById() before you have a View, because the UI doesn’t exist before this call.**

```
ans = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ans);
b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
b2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
b1.setOnClickListener(this);
b2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Call

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

before trying to access your buttons and edit text

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ans = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ans);
        b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
        b2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```